# change component property which is mapped

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am using redux to track which screen user is at.

I have a button tab component:

Tab.js:

```
class Tab extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate(route)}>
        <Icon
          style={selected ? deviceStyle.tabSelectedColor : deviceStyle.tabDefaultColor}
          type="Ionicons"
          name={icon}
        />
        <Text style={selected ? deviceStyle.tabSelectedColor : deviceStyle.tabDefaultColor}>
          {title}
        </Text>
      </Button>
    );
  }
}
```

Then I call it from another component:

```
const items = [
{
  screen: 'home',
  title: 'home',
  icon: 'apps',
  route: 'Home'
}]

renderTab = () => {
    return items.map((tabBarItem, index) => {
      return (
        <Tab
          key={index}
          title={tabBarItem.title}
          icon={tabBarItem.icon}
          route={tabBarItem.route}
        />
      );
    });
  };
```

Now, when user change screen, how can I change the `selected props in tab component`?

Comment: Where are you setting the "selected" prop?

Comment: It should be pass from the renderTab.

Comment: Are you using react-router-dom?

Comment: react-navigation

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this.
1) Onclick / onpress  of your `Tab` you can dispatch an action, which will update user's current screen, as currently, you are navigating user on that page.
2) On load of screen, which is going to load after tab click/press.

You just need an action which will update user's current screen